# Using std::to_wstring with libstdc++?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, libstdc++

Why this doesn't compile on gcc?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
int main() {
 
    double f = 23.43;    
    std::wstring f_str = std::to_wstring(f);
    std::wcout << f_str << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:6:26: error: ‘to_wstring’ is not a member of ‘std’

[example](http://ideone.com/rIAm93)

Comment: What version of GCC and libstdc++ are you using?

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++11` and defining `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`?

Comment: @Antonijn, you should not be defining `__GCC_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`, leave it to the compiler, do not do that. Do not ever do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::to_wstring()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) was added in C++11. The link in your answer, on ideone, is *not* using the C++11 compiler:

> language:  C++ (gcc-4.7.2)

It compiles fine: http://ideone.com/UO2FQM :

> language:  C++0x (gcc-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

Your program compiles IF you choose C++0x in IDEONE instead of C++ because its a C++11 feature.